# Not a debuggee or not listening for a debugger to attach

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, debian

I want to attach a debugger to a github project called [Mamute](https://github.com/caelum/mamute).  run.sh wires up the application.  `cat run.sh`reads:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

MAMUTE_DIR=$SCRIPT_DIR

TIMESTAMP=BUILD_TIMESTAMP

WEB_INF=${SCRIPT_DIR}/WEB-INF

java -cp ${WEB_INF}/classes/:${WEB_INF}/lib/* \
    -Ddeploy.timestamp=$TIMESTAMP \
    -Dvraptor.webappdir=${MAMUTE_DIR} \
    ${MAMUTE_OPTS} \
    br.com.caelum.vraptor.server.Main \
    not-grunt
```

I don't know what "java -cp XXX" means.  I know this is a web app so I tried to attach to the PID just like I would if I were debugging something in windows using visual studio.

After launching netbeans with "gksu /usr/bin/netbeans", I go to top menu > Debugger > Attach Debugger >

- Java Debugger (JPDA)
- Process Attach (by pid)
- Transport = local
- PID = XXXX (XXXX obtained by running "lsof -i :8080)

Click Attach. Error:

> Not a debuggee or not listening for a debugger to attach.

I'm running Debian.

Comment: The java command line options are documented online or in manpages. `-cp` is defining the classpath. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you can run mamut in debug mode adding the following options to the java command in `run.sh`

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1000,server=y,suspend=n
```

You then have to attach the debugger in netbeans choosing the dt_socket transport option.

Note that, if suspend is 'n', the application will start immediately and will not wait for a debugger to attach to it. If 'y', the application will be suspended until you attach to it.